# Run PHP script from jQuery then submit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On submit of a the `consent` form, I need to run a PHP script. Once the script has run I want to submit the `consent` form as usual.

I had thought something similar to the following would work:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#consent', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get('http://www.domain.co.uk/test.php', function() {
    console.log('returned');
    $('form#consent').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: research `ajax`

Comment: This is wrong, the event on submit is calling a PHP and in the return you need submit (again) the form? What is the need to do this?

Comment: What is not working with the code you have?`It looks correct

Comment: @mplungjan The PHP script is run, but the form isn't submitted.

Comment: Do you have a form field called submit? Then rename it

Comment: @mplungjan no fields are called 'submit'.

Comment: Please show the html. It should work - try changing the second submit to `$('form#consent')[0].submit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would result in a loop of `submit` events, because your event listener will always gets triggered over and over again. Use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead, to only listen to the first submit:

```
$('form#consent').one('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('http://www.domain.co.uk/test.php', function() {
        console.log('returned');
        $('form#consent').submit();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Another idea to prevent race conditions and other problems, don't use a `submit` button in your form. Just use a normal button and let js do the `submit`.

```
// <button class="send">submit form</button>
$('form#consent button.send').one('click', function() {
    $.get('http://www.domain.co.uk/test.php', function() {
        $('form#consent').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This is mostly working. For some reason, on the first 'click' of the forms submit button, nothing happens. If you click it again, it submits. Any ideas?

Comment: `$('form#consent')[0].submit();` will not trigger the submit handler

Comment: @mplungjan I get $(...)[0].submit is not a function

Comment: This could possibly be a race condition. How long does the request to the php script run? If you click on the submit before the request has finished, you would submit the form anyway. Maybe add some more console logging to see how your script is working and have a look to the network panel to see the time it takes.

Comment: Another idea in my answer to prevent this @ccdavies

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#form').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {
   //your code
  return false;
}).on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```